# CMake: install without resolving dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have a header-only library. My CMakeLists.txt is used to compile some examples. To do so, in the CMakeLists.txt file, I have

`ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(examples)`

I am trying to use

`INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/HeadersOnlyDirectory DESTINATION include)`

to provide an install target, but this ends up having all of the executables in examples as dependencies. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not install headers as files instead? Looks much cleaner to me.

You can obtain the list of them easily by using a glob expression:

```
file(GLOB header_files ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/HeadersOnlyDirectory/*.h)

install(FILES ${header_files} DESTINATION include)
```

Comment: Does installing them as files remove the "all" dependency?

Comment: @par It doesn't matter as you will only install headers and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This behaviour can be induced by adding:

`set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY true)`